# Scraping price of retailers website using excel

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I've created a macro to scrape prices of a retailers website using TagName, this does work however as soon as the TagName moves position I have to relocate and change location number.

I'm currently using an IF function to hedge my bets in terms of targeting the price. Ideally I need to use the Class or ID to bring back the price but i've failed on several attempts.

Website:
https://www.usc.co.uk/puma-roma-basic-perforated-trainers-023210?colcode=02321069

Style 023210/69 (first 6 digits = sName) (last 2 = SCOL)

Any helps would be much appreciated! Below is my current code

```
Sub browse()

 Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
Dim sPath As String, sPathEnd As String, sName As String, SCOL As String

 sName = ActiveCell.Value
 SCOL = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer


IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://www.usc.co.uk/" & sName & "?colcode=" & SCOL & ""

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

''Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = IE.Document
Dim SellingPrice As String
Dim OriginalPrice As String
Dim SellingPrice2 As String
Dim OriginalPrice2 As String

SellingPrice = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")(154).innerText)
OriginalPrice = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")(155).innerText)
SellingPrice2 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")(111).innerText)
OriginalPrice2 = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")(112).innerText)


If SellingPrice = "Add to bag" Then


  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = SellingPrice2
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = OriginalPrice2
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select

Else


  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = SellingPrice
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = OriginalPrice
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
End If

Loop


 Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: And your expected output if I consider the URL you have pasted on top?

Comment: You should loop all the elements to make sure you get the right one. Check [HtmlElement.GetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). You could loop for all spans and make sure you get the right ones if `class=productHasRef`, for example, or maybe selecting the divs by ID and then getting the Innertext.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work for you, instead of using the Span, I used the ID for the Selling Price and the Original Price:

```
Sub browse()

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Dim sPath As String, sPathEnd As String, sName As String, SCOL As String

     sName = ActiveCell.Value
     SCOL = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "https://www.usc.co.uk/" & sName & "?colcode=" & SCOL & ""

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document
    Dim SellingPrice As String
    Dim OriginalPrice As String
    Dim SellingPrice2 As String
    Dim OriginalPrice2 As String


    SellingPrice = doc.getElementbyID("dnn_ctr103436_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl07_lblSellingPrice").innerText
    OriginalPrice = doc.getElementbyID("dnn_ctr103436_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl26_lblTicketPrice").innerText

    If SellingPrice = "Add to bag" Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
      ActiveCell.Value = SellingPrice2
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
      ActiveCell.Value = OriginalPrice2
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
    Else
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
      ActiveCell.Value = SellingPrice
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
      ActiveCell.Value = OriginalPrice
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
    End If

Loop
 Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Also instead of using ActiveCell, in this example I've made the code loop from A1 down until it finds a cell without any data:

```
Sub browse()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required

Count = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Range("A" & Count))
    Dim sPath As String, sPathEnd As String, sName As String, SCOL As String

    sName = ws.Range("A" & Count)
    SCOL = ws.Range("B" & Count)

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "https://www.usc.co.uk/" & sName & "?colcode=" & SCOL & ""

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document
    Dim SellingPrice As String
    Dim OriginalPrice As String

    SellingPrice = doc.getElementbyID("dnn_ctr103436_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl07_lblSellingPrice").innerText
    OriginalPrice = doc.getElementbyID("dnn_ctr103436_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl26_lblTicketPrice").innerText

    ws.Range("C" & Count).Value = SellingPrice
    ws.Range("D" & Count).Value = OriginalPrice
    Count = Count + 1

Loop
ws.Cells.Select
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Both work perfectly! Thank you so much, this was racking my brain... will be using both moving forward!

Comment: @DannyBrown Please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks.